# Error 1170: Function does not return av value

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm new to flash and I'm making a game that's controlled with the mouse. But I'm getting this error  :

Error 1170: Function does not return a value.

I'm trying to write a getter to return bulletType to the main.as

```
public function get(_bulletT:String):String
{ 
    for (var i = 0; i < _bulletT.length; i++) 
    {
        if (_bulletT.charAt(i) == "star")
        {
            return "star";
            "star";
        }
        else 
        {
            return "circle";
            "circle";
        }
    }
```

What value is it asking for?

Comment: Please try to explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, highlight the code with tags and format it correctly. My guess for this error is that your return statements might not be reachable if, for instance, _bulleT.length is <= 0. BTW, naming a function `get(...)` is a bad practice, unless you wanted it to be a getter, in which case, it should be `get bulletType():String`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you format your codes in the future. Also, it is best not to write your code in one line since it gives no additional benefit. Your codes will be compiled into object codes that the flash player will execute.

Anyway, there are a few things wrong with your function. First source of error is that you are enclosing your return values in an if/else block. The function body itself does not specify a return. Here is how your codes should look:

```
        public function get(_bulletT:String):String {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < _bulletT.length; i++) {
                if (_bulletT.charAt(i) == "star") {
                    return "star";
                } 
            }
            return "circle";
        }
```

Notice that you only want to return "star" if the condition is met. Once you return a value, the loop will terminate and the function will exit. The other case is, if the condition is not met in the loop, then the function should return circle. However, this function does not make sense. I believe you are testing to see whether a string contains the word "star" right? If that is the case, then you can just do:

```
        public function get(_bulletT:String):String {
            if (_bulletT.indexOf("star") != -1) {
                return "star";
            } 
            return "circle";
        }
```

However, I do not think thats what you really want. You probably want to determine if **_bulletT** holds the value star. So if that is the case, then you can do:

```
    public function get(_bulletT:String):String {
        if (_bulletT == "star") {
            return "star";
        } 
        return "circle";
    }
```

you are naming your function **get**, which is a reserved word in Actionscript when working with classes and creating getters/setter properties for the class. Anyway, I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario the function may indeed return nothing at all when the length of `_bulletT` is zero – it won't enter the `for` block at all, and that (according to the code you've provided) is the only place where you have `return` statements.

Maybe try adding another `return` statement after the `for` block? Or throw an error before  the `for` if the length is zero?